# Program crashes when I open it (CDM) . Works fine in (IDLE)

Tags: python, crash

I just finish my homework for my python class and for some reason it can't open in CDM. It opens and run fine while i'm in IDLE mode. My friend code looks the same as mine but his can run in CDM. My open and crashes really fast. I thought it was something in my main since if it was my other functions I would be able to pass through the first input. My friend and I look over my code and found nothing wrong and confused why is this happening. Since we are computer noobs I though I would take it here and yes my first post lol. Can someone help me find my error?

```
#Allen
#CSC 110.09
#11/15/2014
#Home Work 8

def main(): #main
#The following should be displayed in the read file
#introduction
print('This program reads data from a file, calculate the statistics and then write the results             to another file.')
print()
print('THIS PROGRAM WILL FIND:')
print()
print('• number of characters')
print('• number of letters')
print('• number of consonants')
print('• number of digits')
print('• number of white-space')
print('• number of word characters')
print('• number of punctuation characters')
print()
#flag
error_loop = False #making a loop so the user enter a valid file

while error_loop == False:
    try:

        original_file = input('Enter a file name:   ') #user input a file to read

        print()

        old_file = open(original_file, 'r')
    except Exception as nope:
        print(original_file, 'not found. Please try again', nope)
        print()

        found = False
    else:

        error_loop = True

try:
    characters_count = 0 #set counting to 0
    letters_count = 0 #set counting to 0
    consonants_count = 0 #set counting to 0
    digits_count = 0 #set counting to 0
    whitespaces_count = 0 #set counting to 0
    wordcharacters_count = 0 #set counting to 0
    punctuation_count = 0 #set counting to 0

    #reading the file
    read_file = old_file.read()

    #counting the stats
    while read_file != '':
        #counting the characters
        characters_count += characters(read_file)
        #counting the letters
        letters_count += letters(read_file)
        #counting the consonants
        consonants_count += consonants(read_file)
        #counting digits
        digits_count += digits(read_file)
        #counting white spaces
        whitespaces_count += whitespaces(read_file)
        #counting word characters
        wordcharacters_count += wordcharacters(read_file)
        #counting punctuations
        punctuation_count += punctuation(read_file)

        #read the file again
        read_file = old_file.read()

except Exception as nope:
    print()
    print(nope)

else:
    #making the new file
    new_file_name = input("please enter a new file name:  ") #user can rename the new file
    new_file = open(new_file_name + ".txt",'w') #call the new file
    new_file.write('Statistics for ')
    new_file.write(original_file)
    new_file.write(':\n')

    new_file.write('\tCharacters: ')
    new_file.write(str(characters_count)+'\n')

    new_file.write('\tLetters: ')
    new_file.write(str(letters_count)+'\n')

    new_file.write('\tConsonants: ')
    new_file.write(str(consonants_count)+'\n')

    new_file.write('\tDigits: ')
    new_file.write(str(digits_count)+'\n')

    new_file.write('\tSpaces: ')
    new_file.write(str(whitespaces_count)+'\n')

    new_file.write('\tWord characters: ')
    new_file.write(str(wordcharacters_count)+'\n')

    new_file.write('\tPunctuation:')
    new_file.write(str(punctuation_count)+'\n')

finally:

    #closes the file
    old_file.close()
    new_file.close()

    print()
    print("we have created a new file called", new_file_name)


def characters(characters): #function 1

return len(characters) #length of characters


def letters(letter): #function 2

letters_total = 0
letters = ['A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q',\
           'R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h',\
           'i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
#list of the alphabeth
for line in letter:
    if line in letters:
        letters_total += 1
return letters_total


def consonants(consonant): #function 3

consonants_total = 0
consonants = ['B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V',\
              'W','X','Y','Z','b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q',\
              'r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z'] #list of consonats
for line in consonant:
    if line in consonants:
        consonants_total += 1
return consonants_total


def digits(digit): #function 4

digits_total = 0
digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'] #list of numbers
for line in digit:
    if line in digits:
        digits_total += 1
return digits_total


def whitespaces(whitespace): #function 5 

whitespaces_total = 0
search = ' ' # space
for line in whitespace:
    if line == search:
        whitespaces_total += 1
return whitespaces_total


def wordcharacters(wordcharacter): #function 6

wordcharacters_total = 0
wordcharacters = ['@','#','$','%','&','+','-','=','<','>','*','/'] #list of word characters
for line in wordcharacter:
    if line in wordcharacters:
        wordcharacters_total += 1
return wordcharacters_total



def punctuation(punctuations): #function 7

punctuation_total = 0
punctuation = ['!','~','`','^','(',')','_','{','}',\
               '[',']','|','\\',';',':','"',"'",',','.','?'] #list of punctuation
for line in punctuations:
    if line in punctuation:
        punctuation_total += 1
return punctuation_total


main() #Call out main
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the indentation after the def main(): block.

You have...

```
def main(): #main
#The following should be displayed in the read file
#introduction
print('This program reads data from a file, calculate the statistics and then write the             results             to another file.')
print()
print('THIS PROGRAM WILL FIND:')
...
```

What you should have is those print statements indented after you define your main() method. Like this...

```
def main():
    print('indent after definition is started like this')
```

Whether this is the only problem with your code, I have no idea. Try changing that and come back if you have more issues.